# Is there a way to have two cells that reference each other in Excel?

Tags: excel

For example, I want two cells A1 and B2, that equal each other, and when I change A1, B2 changes with it, AND when I change B2, A1 changes with it.

I don't want something like `=A1` in B2's formula, because if I change A1, B2 changes, but not vice versa.

This is more for convenience

Comment: it will give you circular exception error if you use formula. But may be it can be figured out with event procedure

Comment: ^ Look up the worksheet change event. This is doable with VBA.

Comment: @user11982798 A circular exception doesn't have to be a show stopper because iterative calculations can enabled in the options.  The roadblock block forcing a VBA solution is the OPs requirement to edit the cell.  A cell does not have the ability to retain a formula while accepting manual input.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'll play around with VBA.